# apps with google maps will work in ios6

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios6, ios6-maps

Apps built with google maps(iOS5), will work perfectly when users update their devices to iOS 6? There are backward compatibility?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they should work fine. The API hasn't changed.

The new maps look a bit different, but functionally they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed one issue: With the new maps you can not display a map of the whole world (think of `setRegion`). Try yourself to zoom out as much as posible in the maps app.